# OpenCV application fails to build when including highgui.hpp

Tags: c++, opencv

Trying to make a hello-world style opencv program, but fails to compile if I don't include highgui.hpp, yet fails to link if I do include it.

For example, when I include that header, the linker complains:

undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
  Mat &frame;
  Mat grayscale;
  CascadeClassifier &face_cascade; 
  vector<cv::Rect> &faces;
  VideoCapture *capture;  
  ...
```

If I don't include highgui.hpp, then it doesn't compile due to errors like:

'VideoCapture’ was not declared in this scope

I'm using pyimagesearch's vagrant based ubuntu virtual machine that comes with cv2 installed.  The cv2 Python scripts work fine, but just not the c++

Comment: Error you are receiving when you include the library indicates a mismatch between the Opencv library and the c++. Try stating `cv::Mat &frame`

Comment: Thanks, no luck though.     Seems like there's at least someone else that has had this issue:  http://answers.opencv.org/question/25708/undefined-symbols-cv_outputarray_outputarraystd__1vectorcvmat-std__1allocatorcvmat/    The vm looks to use OpenCV 2.4.13.. should I try rebuilding?